# Get live id from WP7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, liveid

how can I get the local windows live id from a mobile phone with windows phone? is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible?

No, you can't access the local user live ID(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can [use a webbrowser control with the live messenger connect SDK](http://To%20create%20a%20desktop%20application%20by%20using%20Messenger%20Connect,%20you%20must%20have%20some%20sort%20of%20web%20browser%20control.) to get the user's information to your server side database, or use other services that offer Windows Live Id authentication such as the [Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/accesscontrol/).

Answer (score -1):

See [How to programmatically extract Windows Phone's LiveID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473742/how-to-programmatically-extract-windows-phones-liveid):

> If you run UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID") you'll get a GUID (the windows live anonymous id), but you can't use that GUID to link it to an Live ID like myliveid@hotmail.co.uk
>   (*not tested/verified*)