# How to programmatically extract Windows Phone's LiveID?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, liveid

Is there any way to look up liveID related to a phone (in a way like myliveid@hotmail.co.uk)? I think it was possible in Android. Wouldn't UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID") be helpful? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID") you'll get a GUID (the windows live anonymous id), but you can't use that GUID to link it to an Live ID like myliveid@hotmail.co.uk