# AccountManager on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, openid, accountmanager

Is there an `AccountManager` on Wp7 similiar to the one in [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)? 
So I can use the phone's already authenticated Google account as openID or something (login to my service without asking for his password).

EDIT to add: I have an Active Directory of users, I know their email addresses. (Including their live id if needed, would have preferred Gmail though) I want to be able to login a user without asking for any password, based on authenticated accounts available on his phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Live ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473742/how-to-programmatically-extract-windows-phones-liveid).

In manifest:

```
<Capabilities>
      ...
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
   < /Capabilities>


using Microsoft.Phone.Info;

string anid = UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID") as string;
string anonymousUserId = anid.Substring(2, 32);
```

Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.trygetvalue%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

So you can get a combination of [Live Id and Device](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/09/windows-phone-7-how-to-find-the-device-unique-id-windows-live-anonymous-id-and-manufacturer/) id to identify the user+device.

Comment: yeah but I can't use this for authentication... :(

Comment: Why not? Let him to create an account and connect it whith live id. Then instead of asking a password check the live id.

Comment: but I dunno the live id. I only know a GUID unique to his live id!

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I can't see the difference. If you don't need to send e-mails, why not to store the GUID instead of e-mail? If you need an e-mail - ask user to input it.

Comment: I have an Active Directory of users, I know their email addresses. (Including their live id if needed, would have preferred Gmail though) I want to be able to login a user without asking for any password, based on authenticated accounts available on his phone.

Comment: Unfortunately, GUID is the only info, you can get without asking user to input it manualy.