# Access Windows Live ID/Facebook authentication in Windows Phone programmatically

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-live-id, onedrive

I have a Windows Phone which is linked to Windows Live ID and Facebook accounts. 
I want to use this built-in Windows Live Id information to access SkyDrive (Just like Microsoft Office Mobile and other does). Particularly, I dont want to use SkyDrive API for Windows Phone 7.5 and rewrite the whole code again for user's discovery and authentication. Because, I believe that if the user's phone can sync to SkyDrive, the user is already authenticated to access skydrive and other Microsoft online services. And the similar case for Facebook access through Windows Phone.

But i cant figure it out, as how can i discover this built-in authentication information.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get live id from WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288736/get-live-id-from-wp7)

Answer (score 2):

WP7 doesn't give you the IDs. You'll have to use SkyDrive's / Facebook's APIs to get the credentials and required information.

The user has to explicitly grant your very app access to SkyDrive / Facebook. Even if the user has granted his phone's operating system (and built-in apps) access, this doesn't mean that any other app may automatically access SkyDrive / Facebook.

SkyDrive has an easy to use SDK (it provides a Button control which does everything you need) and I guess for Facebook there are SDKs as well.

Comment: but many of the Microsoft Apps automatically connect to Windows Live services like skydrive, xbox connect etc... and of course these apps do not take separate live id authentication explicitly from user. It could be the fact that, the information can only be accessible using some API which are not exposed to developers in current release. Afterall, all these apps are created in .net, so there could be some api's but might be hidden to 3rd party developers

Comment: The answer is correct. There are no APIs exposed in the SDK that achieve this goal.